# VBS Copy Dir to Active USB Drive

Tags: vbscript, usb, copying

Looking to have a vbscript that can copy a folder and its contents to a active usb drive. So the script need to found the active usb drive put in it. Next copy the folder and its contests to the usb drive. Then after the copy job it done need to tell it's finish. There is what I get so far for it.

```
Const OverWriteFiles = True
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.CopyFolder "C:\Test" , "?:\Test" , OverWriteFiles 'the "?:\Test" is the part set the usb drive at.
Wscript.Echo "I am Done."
```

So, what part I really need help with is found out what the active usb drive letter. Next tell is to copy to that usb drive letter. 
I know it's not alot of code. But, any info wold be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example shows the type of each drive:

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sRes = ""
For Each oDrive In oFSO.Drives
    sRes = sRes & "DriveLetter: " & oDrive.DriveLetter & ", DriveType: "
    Select Case oDrive.DriveType
        Case 0
            sRes = sRes & "Unknown"
        Case 1
            sRes = sRes & "Removable"
        Case 2
            sRes = sRes & "HDD"
        Case 3
            sRes = sRes & "Network Drive"
        Case 4
            sRes = sRes & "CD-ROM"
        Case 5
            sRes = sRes & "RAM-Drive"
    End Select
    sRes = sRes & vbNewLine
Next
MsgBox sRes
```

Your script should be like this one:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each objDrive In objFSO.Drives
    If objDrive.DriveType = 1 Then
        objFSO.CopyFolder "C:\Test" , objDrive.DriveLetter & ":\Test" , True
        MsgBox "Copy to " & objDrive.DriveLetter & " Completed"
    End If
Next
```

UPD: Last drive can be found this way:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each objDrive In objFSO.Drives
    Set objLastDrive = objDrive
Next
MsgBox objLastDrive.DriveLetter
```

Comment: I try running the second part of your code. I get a error about wscript.exe Drive Not Ready error. But, I run the first part of your code give. About what type of drivers  are in your system.Is there a way to make the last driveletter show. I am talking about he HDD type.That it copys too that driver letter?   So like this (objFSO.CopyFolder "C:\Test" , objDrive.LastDriverLetter & ":\Test" , True ) I would like to thank you for the code you have giving me.

Comment: Thank you for the update.. Thinking with all your help. I have get what I need to do this project with now. I hope one day can help out with someone question too.

Comment: I hate to say this.. How do I make it check for the last drive letter then copy the folder on last drive letter? I try add the (objFSO.CopyFolder "C:\Test" , objDrive.Drive.DriveLetter & ":\Test" ). That line of code didn't work for me.

Comment: Try to add this `objFSO.CopyFolder "C:\Test", objLastDrive.DriveLetter & ":\Test"`

Comment: Thank again for the help.. That line of code work for me..Thank again

Answer (score 0):

Well, there may be more than one "active" USB drive. There's nothing stopping me from plugging flash drives into every available USB port on my computer. But here's how you can identify a USB drive (aka, "Removable Drive") on your computer and copy a folder to it with the `CopyFolder()` function.

```
Const TYPE_REMOVABLE = 1

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For Each Drive In .Drives
        If Drive.DriveType = TYPE_REMOVABLE Then
            .CopyFolder "C:\Test", Drive.DriveLetter & ":\Test", True
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: To let you trying your code.. I get a wscript.exe Drive Not Ready error. the error say "The Drive is not ready for use; its door may be open. Please check drive A: and make sure that a disk is inserted and that the driver door is closed. I have try changing the TYPE_Removable = 2 it copy all the files to every hard driver that is in the system. Just like to target the USB driver only. Just to let you know. I am running this code on a Win 7 64bit system. if that helps